# How do I get a startup sound to play using systemd and aplay?

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to create a systemd unit to play a sound on boot with aplay. My systemd unit is

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Sound
After=sound.target
Requires=sound.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=test
ExecStart=/bin/zsh /home/test/startup_sound.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The shell script is

```
amixer set Master 100%
aplay /home/test/smb_coin.wav
```

When I run the shell script everything works fine. When I start the service it does not play the sound but the systemctl status shows this

```
● startup_sound.service - Startup Sound
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup_sound.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-02-01 21:27:30 CST; 14s ago
    Process: 19264 ExecStart=/bin/zsh /home/test/startup_sound.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 19264 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]: Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Limits: Playback 0 - 87
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Mono:
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19265]:   Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Feb 01 21:27:29 Gemini zsh[19267]: Playing WAVE '/home/test/smb_coin.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
Feb 01 21:27:30 Gemini systemd[1]: startup_sound.service: Succeeded.
Feb 01 21:27:30 Gemini systemd[1]: Finished Startup Sound.
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working? I am using Manjaro and Gnome.

Comment: have you found a fix? im having the same problem on raspbian os